# How can I turn on text to speech in Android?

Tags: text-to-speech

I'm not an Android user and I'm stumped. I've got a friend who wants to turn on text-to-speech on his new phone.

His old phone has a "speech" icon on the screen. When he taps that and then taps text, the text is read out loud. In the screen shot below, the "speech" icon appears near the bottom of the screen between the Música and myMetro apps.

[image: Text to speech screenshot]

I can't find a way to turn this option on on his new Android phone. Even worse, I haven't been able to find that "speech" icon anywhere on the internet. What is that and how do I turn it on? Help!

Comment: It looks like the icon for Google TalkBack  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.marvin.talkback

Comment: Did you try checking at Settings > Accessibility ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! The option is "Select to Speak" but it wasn't available in the version of Google TalkBack installed on the phone. I had to download a new version of Google TalkBack and then the option was there. Thanks to "kirodge" for pointing me to TalkBack.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can activate Android Text to Speech on your device: Go to the Language and input panel and tap on Text-to-speech options at the bottom of the screen. Click on your Preferred Text to Speech engine. You will be able to find Google text-to-speech engine, as well as one from your device manufacturer if any.

Comment: The option appears to be installed and turned on. Google is selected as the engine. The speed and tone are set. I can listen to an example. But the "speech" icon shown in the screen shot above (on the old phone) does not appear on the screen (on the new phone).